# Launch two dialog box in a row, one after the other

Tags: android, events, android-activity, android-alertdialog, lifecycle

I'm quite new at programming in Java for Android, and I might have missed a step that makes that I can't do what I want.

Basically, I would like to launch two dialog boxes, one ater the other. In other words: when the first one is closed, I want the second one to be open.

You'll understant the use of it :

I have got an activity with two fields (main phone number, and main mail address). I am using a ContactPicker activity that does it well and brings me back the correct ID. When the contact has got several phone numbers, I open an AlertDialog to which I pass the list of numbers, and I let the user chose the main one. After updating the right field, I would like to launch the second one to let the user choose the main mail address.
The point is : I can't find any event to trigger the new AlertDialog :

For now, I have tried : activity OnResume, Dialog onDismiss, but with no success (the first one seems to be normal, the second one maybe comes by a wrong use of the call of the AlertDialog.

I have read in the forum that a good practice would be to use new activities. It seems to me a bit expensive for the display of a single list, but I will go for that if I can't find any other answer.

The solution that I could see :

- Use activity and activities results
- Use an invisible field in the calling activities and set an onChange event, the field being modified by the first AlertDialog window (as a trigger)
- Improve my way of handling AlertDialog (I call it in an ActivityOnResult, as found in a post somewhere)
- Raise and trap home made events and listener : I don't know if I can bulid one.

So, maybe I miss something in android philosophy. Can you please help me ?

Here is an extract of the code (thanks to bits of codes picked over the internet) :

```
    // CATCH ContactPicker Result in order to fetch the contact ID 
    // and fill the fields

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    CharSequence[] itemsList = null;
    MyContactsOperations contact = null; //to get contact's details
    String id=null;

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:

                try {

                Uri result = data.getData();

                // get the contact id from the Uri
                id = result.getLastPathSegment();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Unable to get contact infos", e);
                } finally {

                setEditTexts(EDIT_PHONE_NUMBER, id); //use the contact's details to fill the choosen field

                }

                } // END GET PHONE NUMBER           

         }
    }        

private void setEditTexts(int editTextIdx, String idContactPicker) {

    CharSequence[] itemsList = null;
    MyContactsOperations contact = null;

    switch (editTextIdx) {

    /* 
     * Get Phone Number from selected contact 
     */             
    case EDIT_PHONE_NUMBER :

        try {
            contact= new MyContactsOperations();            

            itemsList = contact.getPhoneNumbers(this.getApplicationContext(), idContactPicker);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Unable to get contact infos", e);
        } finally {


            if (itemsList[0]!=null) {
            if (itemsList.length==1) {
                mNumber = itemsList[0].toString();
                setPhoneNumber ();
            }
            else {
                //Launch an AlertDialog Box to choose the right phone number
                selectFromList(itemsList, EDIT_PHONE_NUMBER, idContactPicker);

            }
            }
        }
        break;

    case EDIT_EMAIL :

        try {
            contact= new MyContactsOperations();            

            itemsList = contact.getEMails(this.getApplicationContext(), idContactPicker);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Unable to get contact infos", e);
        } finally {

            if (itemsList[0]!=null) {
            if (itemsList.length==1) {
                mEmail = itemsList[0].toString();
                setEMail();
            }
            else {
                //Launch an AlertDialog Box to choose the right phone number
                selectFromList(itemsList, EDIT_EMAIL, idContactPicker);
            }
            }

        }
        break;
    }
    }


// Method to display the required AlertDialog Box
public void selectFromList(CharSequence[] list, int typeOfList, String id) {

    final CharSequence[] itemsList = list;
    final int type = typeOfList;
    final String idContactPicker = id;

        // build and show a simple dialog that allows the user to select a number
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        switch (type) {
            case EDIT_PHONE_NUMBER :                
                builder.setTitle(R.string.tvMultipleMobile);
                break;
            case EDIT_EMAIL : 
                builder.setTitle(R.string.tvMultipleeMail);
                break;
        }

        builder.setItems(list, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int itemIdx) {
                String uniqueItem = (String) itemsList[itemIdx];
                int startOfItemIndex = uniqueItem.indexOf(":");

                switch (type) {
                case EDIT_PHONE_NUMBER :

                    mNumber = uniqueItem.substring(startOfItemIndex + 2);
                    setPhoneNumber ();
                    setEditTexts(EDIT_EMAIL, idContactPicker);

                case EDIT_EMAIL : 

                    mEmail = uniqueItem.substring(startOfItemIndex + 2);
                    setEMail ();                                    

                }

            }  

            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.setOwnerActivity(this);
            alert.show();
}


public void setPhoneNumber () {

    EditText telEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    telEntry.setText(mNumber);                   

}

public void setEMail () {

    EditText mailEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    mailEntry.setText(mEmail);                   

}

// AND I DON'T KNOW WHERE TO CALL : setEditTexts(EDIT_EMAIL, id);
```

1. Fetch the contact ID from a ContactPicker
2. Call the method to propose the user the list of the multiple phone numbers
3. Build and display the good AlertDialog

But I don't know how to launch the next AlertDialog for the multiple eMails.

Thanks in advance,

eflob

Comment: can you show us the code what have you try?

Comment: Code added to the post. Thanks for your help.